# File.Create and File.OpenWrite does not release the file even if it's closed and also disposed

Tags: c#, file, stream

I am downloading a pdf file using HttpWebRequest object and write the content directly to a FileStream from a response stream, using all "using" blocks and also the .Close method right after the data is copied.
And the next step, I need to extract some text from that pdf file by using some 3rd party library (iText7) but it can't access the file. 
At first, I thought it was the iText7-related issue but then I realized it doesn't seem so because I can't even delete the file from file explorer, getting "file in use" error by my own app.

Here's the sample code:

```
            HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            webReq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            webReq.CookieContainer = Cookies;
            webReq.UserAgent = UserAgent;
            webReq.Referer = Referrer;
            webReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream httpResponseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (FileStream output = File.Create(file1))
                    {
                        httpResponseStream.CopyTo(output);
                        output.Close();
                    }
                    httpResponseStream.Close();
                    response.Close();

                    Cookies = webReq.CookieContainer;
                }
            }

            GC.Collect();

            ExtractPDFDoc(file1);//error throws in this function and the exception.message is "Cannot open document."

            Console.WriteLine("now waiting to let you check the file is in use? try delete it manually...");
            Console.ReadKey(); //added this line to ensure that file is actually in use. I can't even delete the file manually from windows file explorer at this time. But, interestingly, Acrobat Reader can OPEN the file when I double click, which makes me thing that Adobe and iText7 uses different methods to open the pdf file - but anyway - I can't help it tho.
```

Can you please help what is wrong here?

For those who wants to see the ExtractPDFDoc() method:

```
public static object ExtractPDFDoc(string filename)
    {

        iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = null;
        iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = null;


        try
        {

            pdfReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(filename);

            pdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            pdfReader = null;
            pdfDocument = null;

            return new Exception(string.Format("ExtractPDFDoc() failed on file '{0}' with message '{1}'", filename, ex.Message));

            //this is where I get the error, ex.Message is 'Cannot open document.'
            //however, I can open it in Adobe Reader but I can't delete it before closing my app.
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you forcing the garbage collector to act? You almost never have to do that. I suspect that's causing unexpected problems.

Comment: Nope, I added it later I get the error - just a try but didn't help. The error was already there before I added it.

Comment: you shouldn't be calling obj.Close() if you have using (...). Also, do you have the full exception message and/or traceback?

Comment: @LampToast Thanks for the advice, I disabled all the .Close() methods but it's still the same...

Comment: Can we see the ExtractPDFDoc function? I'm assuming that's your own since google turns up no results

Comment: @LampToast Edited the question.

Comment: What if you put a break point before opening the file with iText? When the debugger pauses, can you manipulate the file (rename it, move it, etc) in Windows explorer?

Comment: @howcheng Yes, you are right. It was the iText7 who locks the file again, not the FileStream object.Now I have to deal with a problem with iText7 since Adobe can open the file but it can not... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the iText objects are all IDisposable, so you should be sure to dispose of them as well. Also, I don't know why you're returning an exception instead of just throwing it.

```
public static object ExtractPDFDoc(string filename)
{
    iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = null;
    iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = null;

    try
    {
        pdfReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(filename);
        pdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("ExtractPDFDoc() failed on file '{0}' with message '{1}'", filename, ex.Message), ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        pdfReader?.Dispose();
        pdfDocument?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Unrelated to that, you can also stack your using statements instead of nesting them.

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse())
using (Stream httpResponseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (FileStream output = File.Create(file1))
{
     // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I had checked that before, they are not IDisposable but they support `pdfReader?.Close()` and `pdfDocument?.Close()` methods... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm deeply sorry, thanks to @howcheng, I realized that it was the iText7 which leaves the file open after it's failed to open the document because of one of it's dependency files was missing in the output folder.

It's clear that I should do a `.Close()` on iText7 objects on exception to avoid false perceptions such as this.

Thanks for all your help.